# Cannot send message without a sender address Error in laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I'm trying to send raw mail but I;m getting an error "Cannot send message without a sender address" and I don't seem to see where I'm going wrong. I've provided the sender email in the .env file but it's still giving that error

My Controller!

```
  <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
    
    
    class ContactController extends Controller
    {
        public function show()
        {
            return view('user.contact');
        }
    
        public function store()
        {
            request()->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);
            Mail::raw('it works', function ($message) {
                $message->to(request('email'))
                    ->subject('Hi There');
            });
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    
    }
```

My .env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=log
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

My mail.php file

```
  <?php
    
    return [
    
       
    
        'mailers' => [
            'smtp' => [
                'transport' => 'smtp',
                'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
                'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
                'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
                'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
                'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
                'timeout' => null,
                'auth_mode' => null,
            ],
    
            'ses' => [
                'transport' => 'ses',
            ],
    
            'mailgun' => [
                'transport' => 'mailgun',
            ],
    
            'postmark' => [
                'transport' => 'postmark',
            ],
    
            'sendmail' => [
                'transport' => 'sendmail',
                'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
            ],
    
            'log' => [
                'transport' => 'log',
                'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
            ],



      'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

  
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

My form!

```
 <form action="{{ route('contact')}}" method="post">
     @csrf
    
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>E-mail</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
         @error('email')
         <p style="color: red; font-size: 15px; margin-top: 5px">{{ $message }}</p>
         @enderror
     </div>
    
    
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I'm trying to send raw mail but I;m getting an error

> Cannot send message without a sender address

and I don't seem to see where I'm going wrong. I've provided the sender email in the .env file but it's still giving that error

Comment: Your `MAIL_USERNAME`,
`MAIL_PASSWORD` should not be null

Comment: @STA I need that even when my MAIL_MAILER=log ? and not smtp?

Answer (score 0):

In your env file your username and password are null, you should be able to take the username and password from mailtrap, and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ]);

    $email = $request->email;

    $data = [
            'email'    => $request->email,
        ];

    Mail::send('mail', $data, function ($message) use ($email) {
        $message->to('myemail@gmail.com', 'Email Title')->subject('Test Subject 2');
        $message->from($email, "Sender Name");
    });
    echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
}
```

Comment: ParseError
syntax error, unexpected 'ublic' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Comment: Seems like you misspelled `public` to `ublic`„ `public function store………`

Comment: After fixing the typo
`Target class [App\Http\Controllers\User\Request] does not exist.`

Comment: Define `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` & `use Mail; `on the top

Comment: Btw, did you create a mail templete on `views/mail.blade.php`?

Comment: Yes I did, and now I have the following error! 
`TypeError
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/alphy/blogEngidaFinal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php on line 466`

Comment: I make a typo mistake. Updated

Comment: After updating too!

`Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
 "`

Comment: Are you using laravel 7.x?

Comment: I thought I was using 6 but just confirmed I'm using 7!

Comment: If you are using 7 then `MAIL_MAILER=log`. For laravel 6 or 5 then it should be `MAIL_DRIVER=log` Run `php artisan config:cache` and try again

Comment: It was `MAIL_MAILER=log` from the start of this question!

Comment: `Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code "530"………` this error comes from when use `smtp`„  i don't know whats gonna wrong here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217025/discussion-between-alphy-gacheru-and-sta).

Answer (score 0):

When the configuration is cached the **.env** file no longer gets loaded. Instead Laravel uses the cached configuration so that the app loads quicker.
So when change **.env** file it is a good idea to run **php artisan config:cache**.

Comment: I ran that each time I made change in the .env file!

Comment: Well, another possible problem. I do not see that your config/mail.php file has such lines:

'from' => [
     'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
     'name'    => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME')
],

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear cache in order to prevent this error . use the following commands one by one and your error will be solved .

```
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan route:cache
- php artisan view:clear
- php artisan config:cache
```

Hope it helped you .